# Unable to submit the ajax form multiple times after using .submit() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

This is my code:

```js
var onloadCallback = function() { 
 $( "#submit" ).each(function() {
        grecaptcha.render($( this ).attr('id'), {
            'sitekey' : '6Lcjvi4UAAAAAIR7_ckItF2HfMEFHx427WUDdGDk',
            'callback' : onsubmitforgotpass
        });
    });
};



function onsubmitforgotpass(token) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("form.formajax").submit(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "admin/login/forgotpass.php",
        data: $("form.formajax").serialize(),
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
          $(".forgotpassresult").html(result);
          $(".forgotpassresult").css("opacity", "1");
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
    
    $("form.formajax").submit();
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="" method="post" class="formajax">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

I am unable to submit this ajax form multiple times.

It is probably because of these 2 lines:

`$("form.formajax").submit(function()`
and 
`$("form.formajax").submit();`

If I replace those line with `$("#submit").click(function()` and `$("#submit").click();`

Then I can submit the form multiple times.

Anyway to submit the form multiple times using `.submit();` function? (It will help me in some other part of my code also, so I do not want to use `click();`

Comment: When your function onsubmitforgotpass(token) called? because error is in that part of code. please call your " $("form.formajax").submit(); " when click on submit button.

Comment: I updated my code (Jquery), please see it. @javedrathod

Comment: OK wait i ll check it it and let you know

Comment: function onsubmitforgotpass(token) {$("form.formajax").submit();} put this in document.ready()

Answer (score 0):

hey please test the following things:

Please remove the actions

```
action="abc.com"
```

to

```
action=""
```

add ajax call on button click like below example:

```
  $("#submit").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "admin/login/forgotpass.php",
    data: $("form.formajax").serialize(),
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
      $(".forgotpassresult").html(result);
      $(".forgotpassresult").css("opacity", "1");
    }
  });

});
```

});

Comment: I am sorry, my action is empty in my original code. It was a mistake

Comment: I need the whole code inside `onsubmitforgotpass` because i am using google recaptcha

Comment: please mark my answer right, if it is helpful to you.

Comment: Bro see my updated Jquery code. I need `onsubmitforgotpass` function. I hope u understand now, sorry for not providing it in the first place.